# .htaccess error. Cant find error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

For some reason, without being changed, I have an .htaccess error that will not allow my site to be accessed.
The errors in the logs is

"[Thu Apr 27 09:20:19.310967 2017] [core:alert] [pid 17718] [client ] /home//public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'application/javascript', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

If I remove the 'application/javascript', it just goes down to the next line and says thats an error. My question is, can anyone see where the error is in this file? I have looked and looked by cant see it. Thank you for your time

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

#for codeigniter
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f

RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

# for firewall
<FilesMatch ".*">

Require ip 192.88.134.0/23

Require ip 185.93.228.0/22

Require ip 2a02:fe80::/29

Require ip 66.248.200.0/22

</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

 Header set X-Frame-Options "DENY"

 <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|tt[cf]|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|woff|xml|xpi)$">

     Header unset X-Frame-Options

 </FilesMatch>

 </IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_autoindex.c>

#Options -Indexes

</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>

Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

 # (1)    (2)

 Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

 <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|tt[cf]|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|woff|xml|xpi)$">

     Header unset X-XSS-Protection

 </FilesMatch>

 </IfModule>



Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# | Compression                                                                      |

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

# Force compression for mangled headers.

# http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>

        SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding

        RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding

    </IfModule>

</IfModule>

# Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types

# (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`

#  and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines

#  as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives).

<IfModule mod_filter.c>

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \

                                  application/javascript \

                                  application/json \

                                  application/ld+json \

                                  application/rss+xml \

                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \

                                  application/x-font-ttf \

                                  application/x-web-app-manifest+json \

                                  application/xhtml+xml \

                                  application/xml \

                                  font/opentype \

                                  image/svg+xml \

                                  image/x-icon \

                                  text/css \

                                  text/html \

                                  text/plain \

                                  text/x-component \

                                  text/xml

</IfModule>
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>

Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"

</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# | Expires headers                                                            |

 # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------



# The following expires headers are set pretty far in the future. If you

# don't control versioning with filename-based cache busting, consider

# lowering the cache time for resources such as style sheets and JavaScript

# files to something like one week.


<IfModule mod_expires.c>

ExpiresActive on

ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

# CSS

ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

# Data interchange

ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"

ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"

ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"

ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images

ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

# HTML components (HTCs)

ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

# HTML

ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

# JavaScript

ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"

# Manifest files

ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"

ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

# Media

ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

# Web feeds

ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"

ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

# Web fonts

ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>


<Files 403.shtml>

order allow,deny

allow from all

</Files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the empty lines between those content type arguments in your command starting with `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE`.

The parser processing that dynamic configuration file (`.htaccess` style file) stumbles: it assumes the command is terminated with the empty line and tries to interpret the following line as separate command. Which leads to the error message you receive.

If you really want to keep those empty lines (for readability maybe), you need to *also* terminate them with a backslash (`\`) indicating the the command will *continue* in the next (non empty) line.

Comment: Thank you arkascha. Much appreciated. I have went through the entire file and did the same, eliminating all the spaces where it seemed logical. Site now works

Comment: Great to hear that, sorry if I wasn't really clear here: you need to remove those empty lines only that you placed between parts of a single command that you spread over two line where the first (or more) line is terminated with a backslash. That one indicates that the command is _not_ yet terminated but goes on in the next line (which should _not_ be empty). Apart from that empty lines may very well serve a purpose and enhance readability of the file.

Comment: Oh you were clear, over time that file had more empty lines than filled lines. Using different editors also contributes to how these files are formatted. I just wanted to clean it up. Thanks again